# CSS border-style being reset to "none"

Tags: css, border

In the following code my "column" borders get reset to `style=none` if I remove the `!important` attribute but I can't figure out why. The debugger shows "none" and when I set the style to "solid" through the debugger, my borders show up. I added `!important` as a last resort and it worked, but the consensus is to avoid using !important.

```css
#selection_td {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 75px;
}

#selection_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 75px;
}

.child_row {
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 99%;
  min-width: 99%;
  height: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.column {
  border-style: solid !important;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
}

.color_img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD colspan="2" align="center" id="selection_td">
      <DIV id="selection_div">
        <DIV class="child_row" id="child_2_row">
          <DIV class="column" style="background-color: #F8D583">
            <img id="color_img" src="images/blank.png" width="50">
          </DIV>
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `border: 2px;` use `border-width: 2px;`. Using just `border` you will reset all other attributes to defaults.

Comment: This worked. It would be nice if, once the border is established, that the attribute settings would be cumulative.

Comment: They are normaly, but `border` is _shordhand property_, to set all attributes at once. So instead `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color` you could just write `border: 1px solid red`.

Answer (score 1):

Conflicting border rules. You can combine to avoid this :

```
.column{
     border: solid 2px black;
     border-radius: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
     overflow:hidden;
     width: 50px;
     height: 75px;
}
```